# How do I get the path to the current script with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

How would I get the path to the script in Node.js?

I know there's `process.cwd`, but that only refers to the directory where the script was called, not of the script itself. For instance, say I'm in `/home/kyle/` and I run the following command:

```
node /home/kyle/some/dir/file.js
```

If I call `process.cwd()`, I get `/home/kyle/`, not `/home/kyle/some/dir/`.  Is there a way to get that directory?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html the documentation link of the accepted answer.

Comment: This was helpful for me: `const sqlFolder = path.join(path.join(process.cwd(), 'db'), 'queries');` https://vercel.com/guides/loading-static-file-nextjs-api-route

Answer (score 1740, accepted):

I found it after looking through the documentation again. What I was looking for were the [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename) and [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) module-level variables.

- `__filename` is the file name of the current module. This is the resolved absolute path of the current module file. (ex:`/home/kyle/some/dir/file.js`)
- `__dirname` is the directory name of the current module. (ex:`/home/kyle/some/dir`)

Comment: If you want only the directory name and not the full path, you might do something like this: 
  function getCurrentDirectoryName() {
    var fullPath = __dirname;
    var path = fullPath.split('/');
    var cwd = path[path.length-1];
    return cwd;
  }

Comment: @AnthonyMartin __dirname.split("/").pop()

Comment: For those trying @apx solution (like I did:), this solution does not work on Windows.

Comment: Found it: `var parts = pathString.split(path.sep); return parts[parts.length - 1]` (https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1224)

Comment: Or simply `__dirname.split(path.sep).pop() `

Comment: Or `require('path').basename(__dirname);`

Comment: FYI: Neither of these will work within the interactive node console, but do within scripts.

Comment: If you're using webpack: path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)

Comment: This [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Comment: My advice: only use `path` module, never process paths manually by `splitting` them or similar.

Comment: As linked in a comment above, if you get `__filename is not defined in ES module scope`, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053801/470749

Answer (score 319):

So basically you can do this:

```
fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'settings.json'), 'UTF-8', callback);
```

Use resolve() instead of concatenating with '/' or '\' else you will run into cross-platform issues.

Note: __dirname is the local path of the module or included script. If you are writing a plugin which needs to know the path of the main script it is:

```
require.main.filename
```

or, to just get the folder name:

```
require('path').dirname(require.main.filename)
```

Comment: If your goal is just to parse and interact with the json file, you can often do this more easily via `var settings = require('./settings.json')`.  Of course, it's synchronous fs IO, so don't do it at run-time, but at startup time it's fine, and once it's loaded, it'll be cached.

Comment: @Marc Thanks! For a while now I was hacking my way around the fact that __dirname is local to each module. I have a nested structure in my library and need to know in several places the root of my app. Glad I know how to do this now :D

Comment: Node V8: path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)

Comment: This [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Comment: @RayFoss be careful in general with string operations on directory separators, there can be surprises in both parsing and concatenation; I think most operating systems tolerate excessive slashes (e.g., `//////home//////yourname///////` is a valid path), but irresponsible use of concatenation can make something that really is unreadable in some cases if you make assumptions about whether a path will have an ending slash or not, or if a slash accidentally gets appended to a file name like /home/yourname/yourfile.png/

Comment: Isn't `path.join` a bit more suitable than `path.resolve`?

Comment: @RayFoss Symbian and Solaris are a higher priority for you than Windows?

Comment: @forrestthopkinsa basically I don't support any file system that allows forward slashes in file names. Windows exists, but so does WSL, Docker and BusyBox... I can think of no reason to consider DOS idiosyncrasies unless it's for the purpose of writing a POSIX layer, migrating a legacy codebase or making a Filesystem storage adapter; Even then, the cloud is everything and the cloud is 99.9+% Linux.

Answer (score 195):

Node.js 10 supports [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), where [`__dirname` and `__filename` are no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag).

Then to get the [path to the current ES module](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff) one has to use:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
```

And for the directory containing the current module:

```
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
```

Comment: How would I know if I'm writing an ES module or not?  Is it just a matter of which Node version I'm running, or if I'm using import/export keywords?

Comment: ES modules available only with `--experimental-modules` flag.

Comment: --experimental-modules is only required if you are running node version is < 13.2. just name the file .mjs rather than .js

Comment: Yes this works. @Nickensoul or in package.json "type": "module",

Comment: Warning, if you are using a bundler, this is the path to the source file.  If you build and deploy to a different folder, it is still the path to the original source file.

Comment: If someone has troubles getting the __dirname you can use: `const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));`

Comment: This solution worked for me with Bun 1.05

Answer (score 171):

**Use __dirname!!**

```
__dirname
```

The directory name of the current module. This the same as the path.dirname() of the `__filename`.

Example: running node example.js from /Users/mjr

```
console.log(__dirname);
// Prints: /Users/mjr
console.log(path.dirname(__filename));
// Prints: /Users/mjr
```

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

For ESModules you would want to use:
`import.meta.url`

Comment: This survives symlinks too.  So if you create a bin and need to find a file, eg path.join(__dirname, "../example.json"); it will still work when your binary is linked in node_modules/.bin

Comment: Not only was this answer given years earlier, it also [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Answer (score 156):

This command returns the current directory:

```
var currentPath = process.cwd();
```

For example, to use the path to read the file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile(process.cwd() + "\\text.txt", function(err, data)
{
    if(err)
        console.log(err)
    else
        console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Comment: For those who didn't understand **Asynchronous** and **Synchronous**, see this link... http://stackoverflow.com/a/748235/5287072

Comment: this is exactly what the OP doesn't want... the request is for the path of the executable script!

Comment: Current directory is a very different thing. If you run something like `cd /foo; node bar/test.js`, current directory would be `/foo`, but the script is located in `/foo/bar/test.js`.

Comment: It's not a good answer. It's mess a logic beacauese this can be much shorter path than you expect.

Comment: Why would you ever do this; if the file were relative to the current directory you could just read `text.txt` and it would work, you don't need to construct the absolute path

Answer (score 58):

When it comes to the main script it's as simple as:

```
process.argv[1]
```

From the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> ### process.argv
>
> An array containing the command line arguments. The first element will be 'node', **the second element will be the path to the JavaScript file**. The next elements will be any additional command line arguments.

If you need to know the path of a module file then use [__filename](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename).

Comment: @Tamlyn Maybe because `process.argv[1]` applies only to the main script while `__filename` points to the module file being executed. I update my answer to emphasize the difference. Still, I see nothing wrong in using `process.argv[1]`. Depends on one's requirements.

Comment: If main script was launched with a node process manager like pm2 process.argv[1] will point to the executable of the process manager
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js

Answer (score 27):

```
var settings = 
    JSON.parse(
        require('fs').readFileSync(
            require('path').resolve(
                __dirname, 
                'settings.json'),
            'utf8'));
```

Comment: Just a note, as of node 0.5 you can just require a JSON file.  Of course that wouldn't answer the question.

Comment: `__dirname` [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Answer (score 21):

Every Node.js program has some global variables in its environment, which represents some information about your process and one of it is `__dirname`.

Comment: Not only was this answer given years earlier, `__dirname` [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Comment: It's about NodeJs 10, but this answer was published in 2016.

Answer (score 18):

Use the `basename` method of the `path` module:

```
var path = require('path');
var filename = path.basename(__filename);
console.log(filename);
```

[Here](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext) is the documentation the above example is taken from.

As Dan pointed out, Node is working on [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) with the "--experimental-modules" flag.  Node 12 still [supports `__dirname` and `__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#modules_dirname) as above.

---

If you are using the `--experimental-modules` flag, there is an [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag).

The alternative is to get the [path to the current ES module](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff):

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(new URL(import.meta.url));
```

And for the directory containing the current module:

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import path from 'path';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(new URL(import.meta.url)));
```

Comment: On Windows there is a leading / in the path returned using this method.

Answer (score 17):

I know this is pretty old, and the original question I was responding to is marked as duplicate and directed here, but I ran into an issue trying to get jasmine-reporters to work and didn't like the idea that I had to downgrade in order for it to work. I found out that jasmine-reporters wasn't resolving the `savePath` correctly and was actually putting the reports folder output in jasmine-reporters directory instead of the root directory of where I ran gulp. In order to make this work correctly I ended up using `process.env.INIT_CWD` to get the initial Current Working Directory which should be the directory where you ran gulp. Hope this helps someone.

```js
var reporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
var junitReporter = new reporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
  savePath: process.env.INIT_CWD + '/report/e2e/',
  consolidateAll: true,
  captureStdout: true
 });
```

Answer (score 14):

NodeJS exposes a global variable called **`__dirname`**.

**`__dirname` returns the full path of the folder where the JavaScript file resides.**

So, as an example, for Windows, if we create a script file with the following line:

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

And run that script using:

```
node ./innerFolder1/innerFolder2/innerFolder3/index.js
```

The output will be:
**C:\Users...<project-directory>\innerFolder1\innerFolder2\innerFolder3**

Comment: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope

Comment: @TranQuocBao If you want to solve your error __dirname is not defined in ES module scope. Import and use the dirname() method from the path module.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `pkg` to package your app, you'll find useful this expression:

```
appDirectory = require('path').dirname(process.pkg ? process.execPath : (require.main ? require.main.filename : process.argv[0]));
```

- `process.pkg` tells if the app has been packaged by `pkg`.
- `process.execPath` holds the full path of the executable, which is `/usr/bin/node` or similar for direct invocations of scripts (`node test.js`), or the packaged app.
- `require.main.filename` holds the full path of the main script, but it's empty when Node runs in interactive mode.
- `__dirname` holds the full path of the *current* script, so I'm not using it (although it may be what OP asks; then better use `appDirectory = process.pkg ? require('path').dirname(process.execPath) : (__dirname || require('path').dirname(process.argv[0]));` noting that in interactive mode `__dirname` is empty.
- For interactive mode, use either `process.argv[0]` to get the path to the Node executable or `process.cwd()` to get the current directory.

Answer (score 8):

You can use process.env.PWD to get the current app folder path.

Comment: OP asks for the requested "path to the script". PWD, which stands for something like Process Working Directory, is not that. Also, the "current app" phrasing is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

index.js within any folder containing modules to export

```
const entries = {};
for (const aFile of require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname, { withFileTypes: true }).filter(ent => ent.isFile() && ent.name !== 'index.js')) {
  const [ name, suffix ] = aFile.name.split('.');
  entries[name] = require(`./${aFile.name}`);
}

module.exports = entries;
```

This will find all files in the root of the current directory, require and export every file present with the same export name as the filename stem.

Answer (score -4):

If you want something more like $0 in a shell script, try this:

```
var path = require('path');

var command = getCurrentScriptPath();

console.log(`Usage: ${command} <foo> <bar>`);

function getCurrentScriptPath () {
    // Relative path from current working directory to the location of this script
    var pathToScript = path.relative(process.cwd(), __filename);

    // Check if current working dir is the same as the script
    if (process.cwd() === __dirname) {
        // E.g. "./foobar.js"
        return '.' + path.sep + pathToScript;
    } else {
        // E.g. "foo/bar/baz.js"
        return pathToScript;
    }
}
```

Comment: `__dirname` and `__filename` are [no longer available with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).