# Proper way to reference files relative to application root in Node.JS

Tags: linux, node.js

I have a Node.JS application running on Linux at AWS EC2 that uses the fs module to read in HTML template files.   Here is the current structure of the application:

```
/server.js
/templates/my-template.html
/services/template-reading-service.js
```

The HTML templates will always be in that location, however, the template-reading-service may move around to different locations (deeper subdirectories, etc.)  From within the template-reading-service I use fs.readFileSync() to load the file, like so:

```
var templateContent = fs.readFileSync('./templates/my-template.html', 'utf8');
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './templates/my-template.html'
```

I'm assuming that is because the path './' is resolving to the '/services/' directory and not the application root.  I've also tried changing the path to '../templates/my-template.html' and that worked, but it seems brittle because I imagine that is just resolving relative to 'up one directory'.  If I move the template-reading-service to a deeper subdirectory, that path will break.

So, what is the proper way to reference files relative to the root of the application?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try

```
var templateContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../templates') + '/my-template.html', 'utf8');
```

Comment: Isn't __dirname actually the path to where the current script/module is?  So in my example, when executing from within 'template-reading-service.js' wouldn't __dirname resolve to '/services/'?

Comment: @user1438940 I thought you executes the file reading code in `/server.js`. Try "../templates/my-template.html"

Comment: no, the code executing the fs.getFileSync is in the "template-reading-service.js".  I don't want to use "../"; that's the entire point of my question.  If I use "../" and then later I move "template-reading-service.js" from the "/services/" directory to "/services/templating/" then all my code breaks.  Or, if I want to have the path to the template directory as a setting in a global config, which would then be used by 20 different other services, all located at different places in the directory structure, then "../" would not work from everywhere

Comment: @user1438940 process.cwd() returns the absolute path of "js" file executed. Therefore you can run a js file in the root directory of the project directory and attach the rest at the end.

Comment: @InspiredJW process.cwd() returns the path of the parent directory of the js file running as the node process, not the js file it is executed in.

Comment: @InspiredJW it looks like you edited out your __dirname advice, but I ended up using it as my solution.  In a global config, I used the following, which still seems pretty crappy to me....  `templates: { directoryPath: path.join(__dirname, '../templates/') }`

Comment: So for anybody else  that was trying to access the file in a relative way, like you do with require,  you can't, you need the FULL_PATH (how you find it is a subjective thing)

Answer (score 34):

To get an absolute filesystem path to the directory where the node process is running, you can use `process.cwd()`. So *assuming* you are running **/server.js** as a process which implements **/services/template-reading-service.js** as a module, then you can do the following from **/service/template-reading-service.js**:

```
var appRoot = process.cwd(),
    templateContent = fs.readFileSync(appRoot + '/templates/my-template.html', 'utf8');
```

If that doesn't work then you may be running **/service/template-reading-service.js** as a separate process, in which case you will need to have whatever launches that process pass it the path you want to treat as the *primary* application root. For example, if /server.js launches **/service/template-reading-service.js** as a separate process then **/server.js** should pass it its own process.cwd().

Comment: So, I thought this might work for me, but it doesn't work in all of my environments.  In my production environment, I'm using `forever` so `process.cwd` returns `/`.

Comment: For any future people looking at these answers: process.cwd is not *necessarily* the answer you're looking for. On windows, for example, if you run a node process from a .bat file, process.cwd() returns the path to the .bat file, not to the root of your node project. I believe similar rules apply to Linux and Mac.

Comment: `process.cwd()` returns the path of the directory where the entry script was *called* from, not the directory where the files is *located*. So, if you call `index.js` from `/var/www/project`, `process.cwd()` will be '/var/www/project', but if you call the same script from `/var/www` it will be `/var/www`.

Answer (score 21):

Accepted answer is wrong. Hardcoding `path.join(__dirname, '../templates')` will do exactly what is not wanted, making the `service-XXX.js` file break the main app if it moves to a sub location (as the given example `services/template`).

Using `process.cwd()` will return the root path for the file that initiated the running process (so, as example a `/Myuser/myproject/server.js` returns `/Myuser/myproject/`).

This is a duplicate of question [Determine project root from a running node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265798/determine-project-root-from-a-running-node-js-application).

On that question, the `__dirname` answer got the proper whipping it deserves.
Beware of the green mark, passers-by.

Comment: I had a horrible time using the app-root-path package.  There were two ways to start my app, node lib/my_app.js or bin/my_app.js.  `path.join(__dirname)` I spent lots of time and code patching app-root-path to work across platforms, ultimately I switched to `path.join(__dirname)` which will work as long as the project files don't shift around.

Comment: For any future people looking at these answers: process.cwd is not *necessarily* the answer you're looking for. On windows, for example, if you run a node process from a .bat file, process.cwd() returns the path to the .bat file, not to the root of your node project. I believe similar rules apply to Linux and Mac.

Answer (score 6):

For ES modules, `__dirname` is not available, so read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053801/10190810) and use:

```
import { resolve, dirname, join } from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import fs from 'fs'

const relativePath = a => join(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), a)

const content1 = fs.readFileSync(relativePath('./file.xyz'), 'utf8') // same dir
const content2 = fs.readFileSync(relativePath('../file.xyz'), 'utf8') // parent dir
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use path madule to access the current path

```
const dirname = __dirname;
const path = require('path');


path.resolve(dirname, 'file.txt')
```

where

```
dirname  - is give us present working directory path name
file.txt - file name required to access
```