# How should I load a file that is inside my own module?

Tags: node.js, require

Current code in `/config/index.js`

```
const options = (require('js-yaml')).safeLoad(
  (require('fs')).readFileSync(`./config/default-config.yaml`, "utf8"));

module.exports = options;
```

Works fine. Until I publish and use it in my other project. Then it's unable to find the file (naturally) as `./config/default-config.yaml` doesn't exist in that project.

The only option I can think of involves checking to see if the file exists at that path, then trying to load it from `node_modules/@company/alpha-gamma/config/default-config.yaml`. This seems really hacky.

The config object is large, 200+ keys. I don't think it belongs in the code.

What's the best solution for loading a file that exists inside your module? I need to be able to load it for unit tests before publishing and load it at runtime when the library is required by another module.

Maybe the best alternative is to use `json` since I can then use the `require` module to load it in, instead of `fs`.

Comment: I had intended to point you to this-
 it seems similar.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051961/proper-way-to-reference-files-relative-to-application-root-in-node-js

Comment: don't know why but `__dirname` has always seemed like a hacky trick to me -- like something they meant to remove years ago

Comment: I don't disagree with that at all.  I was rather surprised I didn't find more immediately on this topic.

Comment: Looks like that did it. That `__dirname` just seems so not-Node-ish; seems like a Ruby/Python-ism instead. It's incongruous.

Comment: A bittersweet victory.  Now you are on the proper path to heroism.

Comment: Write it up, you deserve the answer credit.

Comment: Updated my answer three years later. I misinformed you, I believe the proper answer is avoiding `__dirname` and utilizing `process.cwd()` instead. Your reservations on using it were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I originally suggested utilizing `__dirname` as a valid option, I was wrong. Calling `process.cwd()` to fetch the application root and building the path off of that is the best approach.

As documented here:
[Proper way to reference files relative to application root in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051961/proper-way-to-reference-files-relative-to-application-root-in-node-js)