# Node.js not only opening my code in a specific place

Tags: javascript, typescript

My question is, is it possible to do so that when I have a code and a text file, but when I want to open or locate the text file, I dont need to specify it everytime where it is or like when I send it to someone else, they dont need to change the let file = C:\Users\etc...

My code:

```
const { readFile, readFileSync } = require('fs');


let file = 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\Desktop\\word-counter\\TextFile2.txt';

function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
const words = sentence.split(" ").filter(word => !!word);
const wordMap = {};

for (let word of words) {
    const key = word.trim().toLowerCase();
    const currentWordCount = wordMap[key];
    wordMap[key] = (currentWordCount ?? 0) + 1;
}

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(wordMap).sort(([a,], [b,]) => a.localeCompare(b));
const sortedWordMap = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries);

//returning the wordMap and the sorting of the wordMap
return sortedWordMap
return wordMap;

}

words = readFileSync(file).toString();
console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

Comment: You question is unclear, but here is a tip that might help you. Use "__dirname", it is a env variables that refers to the absolute path of the current file.

Comment: Also consider using the `path` module.

Comment: @NizarZizoune `__dirname` is only the current folder, not the current file

Comment: @BaoHuynhLam Good catch thank you. Yes. it refers to the directory containing the current file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper way to reference files relative to application root in Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051961/proper-way-to-reference-files-relative-to-application-root-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, through the `path` (built-in Nodejs) module and the `__dirname` constant. The `__dirname` environment variable will automatically get the current folder's path for you, and then you can use `path.join` to join the current directory with the filename you want to access. Something like this

```js
const path = require("path");

// Assuming that the current script file are inside the 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\Desktop\\word-counter' folder
const file = path.join(__dirname, "TextFile2.txt");

// file = 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\Desktop\\word-counter\\TextFile2.txt'
```

If you put "TextFile2.txt" in a relative position not in the current folder, you can also use `path.join` with the folder traversal syntax such as `..` to go back a folder

```js
const path = require("path");

// Assuming that the current script file are inside the 'C:\\Users\\eeroj\\Desktop\\word-counter' folder
const file = path.join(__dirname,"../../", "TextFile2.txt");

// file = "C:\\Users\\eeroj\\TextFile2.txt"
```

As a result, this way should work regardless of anywhere you put the project, even on a different machine, as long as the project folder structure stays relatively the same and the "TextFile2.txt" file is in the right place relative to the script file.

Answer (score 0):

If your txt file is in the same directory as the script you can simply use the relative path with a '.' as

```
let file = "./TextFile2.txt"
```

Just note that the textfile will have to always have the same name.