# How do you import a .json file into a node.js file when the .json file is in an upper directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-amplify

I have this folder structure in my project. `testproject/backend/amplify/backend/function/newestjavascript/src/index.js`. And `testproject/backend/src/amplifyconfiguration.json`

I want to import `amplifyconfiguration.json` into my `index.js` file and use it. I am trying to use the `require()` statement from node,  but it always tells me my amplifyconfiguration.json file cannot be found even though it clearly exists. I know my folder structure and spelling are not incorrect. Any idea why it will not import my amplifyconfiguration.json file?

Here is my code that does not work:

```
const { Amplify } = require('aws-amplify');
const { signUp } = require('aws- 
amplify/auth');
const amplifyConfig = require("../../../../src/amplifyconfiguration.json");
exports.handler = async (event) => {
try {
  Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
}
```

This code gives me this error: "Cannot find module '../../../../src/amplifyconfiguration.json'"

Comment: don't just tell the case, show the code you have

Comment: I updated the question to show my code

Comment: Did you mean to include the line `const amplifyConfig =` twice?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705219/nodejs-accessing-file-with-relative-path, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051961/proper-way-to-reference-files-relative-to-application-root-in-node-js

Comment: No sorry I did not mean to include that twice. My mistake I have removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:**
It is likely that your script is being run outside of its current directory. In that case, you could try and update your `require` based on the result of `console.log(__dirname)`.

**Approach 2:** You could try using `path.join` instead as it will give you an absolute path to your configuration file. This is also good for debugging because you can check if the path is as you expect. Here is how you would use it:

```js
const pathToAmplifyConfig = path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "..", "..", "src", "amplifyconfiguration.json");
console.log(pathToAmplifyConfig); //This should show you the correct absolute path
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(pathToAmplifyConfig, 'utf8'));
```

Comment: Big thanks for the help Luke! Great ideas to help me figure out what is wrong. Turns out it has something to do with AWS, and not my file. When I run the function locally it works, but when pushing to aws it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can access your json file.

```
const jsonData = require("../../../../src/amplifyconfiguration.json");
```

I will refer you to visit on [this medium](https://medium.com/@Linda_Ikechukwu/understanding-file-paths-165c07ec5cf0) doc and understand `file paths`

Comment: This did not work .It gave me the same error