# How to get filename of script being executed in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

How to get filename of script being executed in NodeJS application?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use variable `__filename`

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename

Comment: This is only useful if you want to know the filename currently running the code that is looking at the `__filename` variable. If, instead, you need to know the name of the entire nodejs program that is running, use @Brad 's answer below.

Comment: This [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Answer (score 28):

Use the `basename` method of the `path` module:

```
var path = require('path');
var filename = path.basename(__filename);
console.log(filename);
```

[Here](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_p_ext) is the documentation the above example is taken from.

As Dan pointed out, Node is working on [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) with the "--experimental-modules" flag.  Node 12 still [supports `__dirname` and `__filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#modules_dirname) as above.

---

If you are using the `--experimental-modules` flag, there is an [alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag).

The alternative is to get the [path to the current ES module](https://medium.com/@nodejs/announcing-a-new-experimental-modules-1be8d2d6c2ff):

```
const __filename = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
```

And for the directory containing the current module:

```
import path from 'path';

const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
```

Comment: This [no longer works with ES modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-do-i-get-the-path-to-the-current-script-with-node-js/50053801#50053801).

Answer (score 24):

You need to use `process.argv`.  In there will be the name of the script that was executed from the command line, which can be different than what you will find in `__filename`.  Which is appropriate depends on your needs.

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv

Comment: how is it different than `__filename`? It looks the same.

Comment: @1252748 You should read the documentation:  https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_filename  `__filename` is the name of the file you're currently in.  If I have a script that includes 5 other modules, there are 6 different possibilities of what `__filename` will be, depending on where I checked.  Furthermore, the script might have a symlink that was used to execute it.  `process.argv` will give you what was actually ran.

Comment: Be careful, be what was actually executed may not be where your script is actually located. In other words, it might be a symlink instead.