# Run Server in MERN application

Tags: mern

I am learning MERN application development. I got a incomplete MERN application and trying to run the application. My `package.json` file is like below.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "machine-shop",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node ace build --production",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "node ace serve --watch",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext=.ts",
    "format": "prettier --write ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@adonisjs/assembler": "^5.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.3",
    "adonis-preset-ts": "^2.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "eslint": "^7.27.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-adonis": "^1.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.17.0",
    "pino-pretty": "^5.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^5.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^11.1.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "~4.2",
    "youch": "^2.2.2",
    "youch-terminal": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "-": "^0.0.1",
    "@adonisjs/auth": "^8.0.4",
    "@adonisjs/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@adonisjs/lucid": "^14.1.0",
    "@adonisjs/repl": "^3.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/session": "^6.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/shield": "^7.0.0",
    "@adonisjs/view": "^6.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^28.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^3.0.2",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "2.6.1",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "1.3.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "5.13.0",
    "@manaflair/redux-batch": "1.0.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.53",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.9.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@tanem/svg-injector": "8.0.50",
    "apexcharts": "^3.27.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.18.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.2.0",
    "clipboard-copy": "3.1.0",
    "clsx": "1.1.0",
    "cp-cli": "2.0.0",
    "css-mediaquery": "^0.1.2",
    "date-fns": "2.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "5.1.0",
    "downshift": "3.4.2",
    "fg-loadcss": "^3.1.0",
    "force": "^0.0.3",
    "formik": "2.1.4",
    "holderjs": "^2.9.9",
    "json2mq": "^0.2.0",
    "luxon": "^1.27.0",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^1.8.3",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.5",
    "phc-argon2": "^1.1.1",
    "phc-bcrypt": "^1.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "proxy-addr": "^2.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "4.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "2.1.2",
    "react-datepicker": "2.16.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^9.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "4.4.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.3.4",
    "react-inlinesvg": "1.2.0",
    "react-intl": "3.6.2",
    "react-is": "16.13.1",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.8",
    "react-portal": "4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "3.1.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.9",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "12.2.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.4.0",
    "react-window": "1.8.5",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "socicon": "3.0.5",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.0.11",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  }
}
```

My `server.js` file is like below

**server.js**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import sourceMapSupport from 'source-map-support';
import { Ignitor } from '@adonisjs/core/build/standalone';

sourceMapSupport.install({ handleUncaughtExceptions: false })

new Ignitor(__dirname).httpServer().start()
```

I am trying to run the application using `npm start` command. But I am getting below error.

```
file:///home/foysal/Music/machineshop/server.js:20
new Ignitor(__dirname).httpServer().start()
            ^

ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/foysal/Music/machineshop/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/foysal/Music/machineshop/server.js:20:13
```

[image]

What is the meaning of this code `new Ignitor(__dirname).httpServer().start()` ? Is it correct code ?

Previously I worked in another MERN application. `server.js` file of that project is not similar like `server.js` file of this project.

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Could any one help me to run the application ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_dirname is not defined in Node 14 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383909/dirname-is-not-defined-in-node-14-version)

Comment: Thanks @funkizer. No. This doesn't answer my question. I would like to run the app. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it does. Did you read your error? __dirname is not defined so you need to find the path to your server.js using other methods

Comment: Thanks @funkizer. How can I find the path to my `server.js` using other methods ?

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up client and server. Usually you keep them separated when you work on stacks like that - in separate repositories or at least in separate directories. You have 2 ways as I see:

- Separate client and server dependencies
- Use Adonis to serve the React app

I would take the first path for better maintainability. If that seems too complicated, you can take the later one for now and keep working on separation down the road. For that you may wanna look into [this](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/routing#routing-for-spa) document.

Answer (score 0):

Running client and server separately will be very painful. For that, I will suggest you run the client and server with a single command.

Install nodemon and concurrently for the backend. Then follow the steps below ...

- Step 1: Go to your package.json file of the backend.
- Step 2: Move to scripts property
- Step 3: Type the command inside scripts like this

  "client": "npm start --prefix frontend"
  "server": "nodemon backend/server"
  "dev": "concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""

This will help you to run the server and client smoothly without any errors.