# Retrieving image from backend using url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

`http://localhost:5000/uploads/1648551005076_download.jpg`

> Error: not found - /uploads/1648551005076_download.jpg
> below is image so you can understand the folder location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ZMp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have added this line to your code

```
import path from 'path'; 

const __dirname = path.resolve();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'))
```

then, try like this
http://localhost:5000/1648551005076_download.jpg

Comment: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope.

Comment: this error pops up when i tried this way

Comment: i have used app.use("/uploads", express.static("uploads"));

Comment: for Error: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope.
add this lines

Comment: import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.resolve();

Comment: Here's the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383909/dirname-is-not-defined-in-node-14-version) of the code

Comment: still not working

Comment: resolved thanks for your precious time