# Can you use __dirname while using type: module in package.json?

Tags: node.js, import

Im getting "__dirname is not defined" when I define `"type": "module"` on package.json. I'm doing this so I can use ES6 imports. How do I get access to __dirname in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for \_\_dirname in node when using the --experimental-modules flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag)

Comment: Check out `import.meta.url`: `import path from 'path'; const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);`