# importing path in nodejs instead of requiring it in the server.js

Tags: node.js, express, import, server, path

file:///D:/Projects/practice/Node/server.js:129
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
^

ReferenceError: path is not defined

i am using imports for express & body parser
& this error keeps showing up.
when i change "type":"module" form json file
& use require instead of imports,it works fine.
can u please help me in importing path.
i tried importing path in different ways but then it shows __dirname isnot defined.
Can u please help me in importing path.

Answer (score 1):

`__dirname` is [not](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/esm.html#esm_no_filename_or_dirname) available when you're using `module` as `type`.

You might look at the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46745014/3776551) for alternative solutions. Or you can even try -

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```