# Issue running puppeteer in github actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, puppeteer, github-actions

Everything works fine locally, but when I try to run my script using puppeteer in github action, I get this:

```
file:///dist/index.js:49412
    const puppeteerRootDirectory = pkg_dir_1.default.sync(__dirname);
                                                          ^

ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/dist/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

I've tried defining the `__dirname` before importing puppeteer but haven't had any luck. e.g.

```
import {dirname} from "path";
globalThis.__dirname = dirname(import.meta.url);
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
```

EDIT:

This appears to be an issue with compiling via ncc. I can repro locally when I run `ncc run [my script]`. I've looked into how to define __dirname for modules but am still running into issues. I tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-when-using-the-experimental-modules-flag) and adding it at the top of my script before my import statement but it doesn't make a difference. Is there anywhere I can add it that it would be recognized by puppeteer?

Comment: what Node version do you use locally and in GH Actions? _Note:_ it is very rare when you can use 'import' instead of 'requiring' to use node modules.

Comment: Locally v14.17.1 and 16 on gh via Docker