# Node Require and Import

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, ecmascript-5

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'folderName'));
```

I want to create directories in node, when I require the modules (commonjs) everything works but when I change the type in my `package.json` to `module` and use imports the folder doesn't get created, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `__dirname` in an ESM module.  You will have to manufacture it from `import.meta.url`.  You can search and find examples for how to do that.  For examples, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242626/816620).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `__dirname` in an ESM module.  If it's something you need, you can manufacture it with this:

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
```

But, many of the functions in the `fs` module can take `import.meta.url` more directly.  See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65895043/816620) for details on that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured `__dirname` isn't available on es6 modules so I just replaced that with `'./'`. You could use an npm package for that if you are looking for elegance.

Comment: `./` will use the current working directory which may or may not be the same as `__dirname`.  In a top level module file in your project, it will be the same thing.  In an imported module from the `node_modules` directory, the current working directory will have no connection at all to what `__dirname` would have been.