# Directory path not defined error in Node - ReferenceError

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, dirname

Trying to get the directory path of my current script in NodeJs using "__dirname". I'm getting Reference Error. What can be wrong

Here's the code (though it's part of a larger code base):

```
import path from 'path'

console.log(__dirname)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3YV4.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for \_\_dirname in Node.js when using ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-js-when-using-es6-modules)