# How can I execute node cli script from another node.js script/module?

Tags: node.js

I have a node library with multiple scripts (ES modules to be precise). One of the module, when invoked, uses [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) function from built-in `child_process` module. I need to run [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) command using the `exec` function.

The problem is that `ts-node` is not recognized as `exec` doesn't do the path manipulation magic that `npm scripts` do by appending the `node_modules/.bin` to the `path` variable. Further, I cannot rely on `__dirname` and `__filename` special values as I use ESM and not CJS (I know there is a way to get these values but I would rather prefer if there is any standard approach to execute commands with the semantics of `npm scripts`).

So, how can I execute `ts-node` command from my own script which could be installed anywhere (as a nested dependency)?

Comment: Is `ts-node` installed globally or locally? You can easily create your own `__dirname` and `__filename` with the exact same behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-js-when-using-es6-modules There is no standard way.

Comment: The `ts-node` is installed locally. I am thinking will `npx ts-node` will do that job. But I am not able to find the official documentation to check if `cwd` is the starting point for `npx` lookup before fetching or looking for `ts-node` in local system cache.

Comment: `npx` traverses upwards until it finds a `package.json`. If it finds one, it checks there if it can find the required module. It's not `cwd`.