# Using Node.js / ES6 how do I set a custom path to a dotenv file?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, dotenv

Setting a custom path to a `.env` file is easy enough when using the [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require) syntax pattern.

```
import { URL } from 'url';
config({ path: new URL('./models/.env', import.meta.url).pathname });
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(rootPath, '/models/.env') });
```

However, I recently added `"type": "module",` to my package.json file and I'm in the process of updating all of my code to use the new ES6 [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax.

The [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) page on NPM and README.md show how to load in es6 but not how to set a path.

```
import 'dotenv/config'
```

I've tried using `.config` after loading dotenv but that doesn't work.

```
import 'dotenv/config'
import { URL } from 'url';
config({ path: new URL('./models/.env', import.meta.url).pathname });
dotenv.config({ path: path.join(rootPath, '/models/.env') });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `dotenv/config` if you need to pass parameters. Use [this approach](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/133#issuecomment-255298822) instead (and also [avoid `__dirname`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651120/1048572)):

*env.js*

```
import { URL } from 'url';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config({ path: new URL('./models/.env', import.meta.url).pathname });
```

*index.js*

```
import './env'; // instead of import 'dotenv/config';
… // your other imports
```