# _dirname is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

I encountered a problem where I received a reference error stating "_dirname is not defined in ES module scope". This occurred after I made a change in the package.json file by setting the type to "module". Could someone please offer a solution?

```
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
console.log(__dirname); // Reference Error: 
// __dirname is not defined in ES module scope
```

Comment: Can you check if in your `package.json` there is a property called `"type"="module"`?

Comment: Set the type back to CommonJS? Or update your code to actually be ESM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for \_\_dirname in Node.js when using ES6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-js-when-using-es6-modules)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

refer to this [documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname), and do it this way

```
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

console.log(__dirname);
```

`import.meta.url` as described [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta_url)

> This is defined exactly as in browsers which provide the URL of the
> current form file.

then adding to your package.json

```
 "type": "module",
```