path.resolve() returns project directory in one environment and parent directory of project in other environment
path.resolve() is not returning expected path.
The code snippet for reference:
import path from "path";
import { moduleLogger } from "../utils/logger.js";
import { oracleQuery } from "./oracleDBConn.js";
import fs from "fs";

const __dirname = path.resolve();
const sql_file_dir = "/oracleDB/SQLs";
const sql_upgrade_file_dir = "/oracleDB/SQLs/upgrades";

NOTE: The node application is accessing node_modules from other directory with symlink.
In ECMAScript modules (ESM), __dirname is not implicitly available. So, I'm using path.resolve() to resolve the base directory for file paths. On my local environment(Windows), on Linux 3.10.0-1160.108.1.el7.x86_64 and on Linux 3.10.0-1160.105.1.el7.x86_64, it works as expected, returns the project directory path. But On client's server, it's returning the parent directory path of the project, resulting in an error while reading the file:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ‘/app/products/ecom/database/sql_files/init.sql’
While the actual path should be ‘/app/products/ecom/ecom_api/database/sql_files/init.sql’.
I tried to reproduce the issue on my environments, but couldn't.

What's the value you get in __dirname ? I should be the path of the working directory. The directory where you ran the program from.

@BrahmaDev Yes, I get the working directory path in all of my environments, but the on the client's environment, they are getting the path of the parent directory of working directory.

This is XY problem. It's not uncommon to have such kind of problems when relying on CWD, especially when links are involved. If you need __dirname  in ESM then you need to do it correctly

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745014/alternative-for-dirname-in-node-js-when-using-es6-modules

As of now, I'm explicitly setting the value for project dir path in an env variable.
