# Node.js - getting current filename

Tags: node.js

How to get current file name, function name  and line number?

I want to use it for logging/debugging purpose, equivalent to `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`  in c

Comment: File: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-to-get-path-to-current-script-with-node-js?rq=1 Line: https://github.com/visionmedia/callsite

Comment: I see nobody ever came up with a good answer for function name or line number.

Answer (score 310):

Node.js provides a standard API to do so: [Path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html).

Getting the name of the current script is then easy:

```
var path = require('path');
var scriptName = path.basename(__filename);
```

Comment: Doesn't this get the basename rather than the actual filename?

Comment: for a script named `script.js`, you'll get `script.js`. If you want to have the name only without extension, as we are speaking here of a `js` script you can use `var scriptName = path.basename(__filename, '.js');` or `var scriptName = path.basename(__filename, path.extname(__filename))`

Comment: another way to drop the extension: `path.parse(__filename).name`

Comment: `__filename` is not defined in an ES6 Module.

Comment: @Cullub, extract from the nodejs [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_no_require_exports_module_exports_filename_dirname):

These `CommonJS` variables are not available in ES modules.
Equivalents of `__filename` and `__dirname` can be created inside of each file via `import.meta.url`.

Comment: You can remove the extension by regex string replace too.
and it can handle upper case letter in filename

`var scriptName = path.basename(__filename).replace(/\.js$/i, '' ); `

Comment: @Cullub `module.filename` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 58):

within a module you can do any of the following to get the full path with filename

```
this.filename;
module.filename;
__filename;
```

If you just want the actual name with no path or extension you can do something like this.

```
module.filename.slice(__filename.lastIndexOf(path.sep)+1, module.filename.length -3);
```

Comment: You probably want to use path.sep to make it cross platform. Here's what I did __filename.slice(__filename.lastIndexOf(path.sep)+1);

Comment: For those who just want to copy and paste this super handy one-liner, don't forget to either `var path = require('path');` beforehand or change it to `module.filename.slice(__filename.lastIndexOf(require('path').sep)+1, module.filename.length -3);`

Comment: the -3 assumes a length of extension, something like this might work better `path.basename(module.filename, path.extname(module.filename))`

Answer (score 54):

To get the file name only.
No additional module simply:

```
// abc.js
console.log(__filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1));

 // abc
console.log(__filename.slice(__dirname.length + 1, -3));
```

Comment: This is what I came here for. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Works in strict mode.  Very straightforward.  Thank you!

Comment: Unless your extension isn't 2 characters long, which is totally possible because you can bind script interpretation to any file extension you want... so this may not be a good all-around solution.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted this. Thank you

Answer (score 27):

```
'use strict';

const scriptName = __filename.split(/[\\/]/).pop();
```

## Explanation

```
console.log(__filename);
// 'F:\__Storage__\Workspace\StackOverflow\yourScript.js'
const parts = __filename.split(/[\\/]/);
console.log(parts);
/*
 * [ 'F:',
 *   '__Storage__',
 *   'Workspace',
 *   'StackOverflow',
 *   'yourScript.js' ]
 *
**/
```

Here we use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function with [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as the first parameter.
The regular expression we want for separator is `[\/]` (split by `/` or `\`) but `/` symbol must be escaped to distinguish it from regex terminator `/`, so `/[\\/]/`.

```
const scriptName = __filename.split(/[\\/]/).pop(); // Remove the last array element
console.log(scriptName);
// 'yourScript.js'
```

## Don't Use This

You really should use `path.basename` instead (first [documented in Node.js v0.1.25](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.1.25/api.html)), because it handles all the corner cases you don't want to know about like filenames with slashes inside (e.g. file named "foo\bar" on unix). See `path` answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28319077/521957).

Comment: Please add explanation

Comment: @DanielCheung Here you are! But really all this is searchable on the Internets, just google `javascript split` and get going.

Comment: I was helping you... -_- Your answer was being voted for deletion. An answer not explaining enough or just containing code **will** get deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You might also look at [console-plus](https://github.com/itadakimasu/console-plus/blob/master/console-plus.js). This adds filename and linenumber to any logging text and has different colours for .log, .info and .error.

Comment: Pretty cool. Install with "npm install --save console-plus", or if you're using yarn: "yarn add console-plus"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ES modules do this:

```js
import path from 'node:path';
const FILE_URL = import.meta.url;
const FILE_NAME = path.basename(import.meta.url);
const FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXT = path.basename(import.meta.url, path.extname(import.meta.url));

console.log({
  FILE_URL,
  FILE_NAME,
  FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXT
});
```

Note: `__dirname` and `__filename` [are not available in Node for ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#no-__filename-or-__dirname).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I wanted to use the file name as the tag for the logger so the most straight forward and what I wanted is this:

```
__filename.substring(__dirname.length + 1, __filename.lastIndexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been already a long time, but what I did is `__filename.split('\\').pop()`. This will get the full path with the filename, split it by `\` then get the last index which will be your filename.

Comment: On macOS `__filename.split('/').pop()`

Comment: On any system `require('path').basename(__filename)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this function to get filename:

```js
/**
 * @description 
 * get file name from path
 * @param {string} path path to get file name
 * @returns {string} file name
 * @example 
 * getFileName('getFileName/index.js') // => index.js
 */
export default function getFileName(path) {
    return path.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
}
```

if you use nodejs, you can install the package that include this function
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jotils

Answer (score 1):

Only because I don't see it listed here, another option is to just remove the `__dirname` from the `__filename`.

```js
__filename.replace(`${__dirname}/`, '')
```

I think that is useful if you don't want to import a the `path` module. However, I do believe that `path.basename(__filename)` is the most appropriate.