# How to find the file name which a function is placed in?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file named Stan_44_API.js and I want to write a function in this file to give me the js file name ( "Stan_44_API" in my case). I will run this code in Node.js by running "node Stan_44_API.js" in command line. How should I write this function to get its filename ( the name of the file which this function code is placed in it) and write it for me?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - getting current filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201475/node-js-getting-current-filename)

Answer (score 0):

Try path Module as below, but can be done in many ways.

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.basename(__dirname));
```