# how to print file name in log in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston, winstone

could you please tell me how to print **file name** in log in node js.it always print `index.js` why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-bassi-ij2e9

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
format: format.combine(
    format.label({ label: path.basename(process.mainModule.filename) }),
    format.timestamp({
      format: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"
    }),

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVmNe.png
```

expected

```
08-01-2020 03:29:33 info [test.js]: --dddabcbbc-
```

why `test.js` is not printed as I mention log in test.js

any update?

Comment: Process.mainModule is not the current module, it’s the module that was launched.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js - getting current filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201475/node-js-getting-current-filename)

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this. The `path` module has a function basename and you just give  it `__filename` global object that is available in every file as an argument.

```
const path = require('path')
console.log(path.basename(__filename))
```