# good dependancy injection module for nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am looking for a good nodejs dependancy injection module,
I implemented a special logger module and I want to be able getting the instance of the logger no matter where my position in the folder hierarchy.
I can't simply use requirejs because with requirejs I need the full relative path to the module. 
Is there a standard suitable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still suggest you to use the `require()` way, since it's native for `node.js`

Though, if you don't want to bother yourself with the relative paths - your module should reside in the `node_modules` folder inside your project. To achieve this, you could install it via `npm`.

But before installing it, you should publish it somewhere, of course.

I would recommend you to take this as a practice:

1. Create a repository for your module ([github](https://github.com/) for public or [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for private repositories)
2. Create a `package.json` file for your module. Here is an example:

   ```
   {
       "name": "your-module",
       "private": true,
       "repository": {
           "type": "git",
           "url": "git@bitbucket.org:username/your-module.git"
       },
       "main": "index.js",
       "version": "1.0.0",
       "dependencies": {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a dependency to this module into your main `package.json` like this

   ```
   "your-module": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org:username/your-module.git#1.1.0",
   ```
4. Run `npm install`
5. Profit

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend following Node.js conventions.

It is possible to store the [location of the current file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-to-get-path-to-current-script-with-node-js), for instance in the main file (supposedly at the root of your project) using `dirname` or `filename`. Then, storing it in the [`global` variable](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global) will make it accessible from everywhere in your app. I find it quite dirty though.