# What is the proper way to point my module to a config directory using config.js?

Tags: node.js

I built a node module for others to import into their node projects.  I use config.js.  I'm having issues telling their scripts where to look for my config directory is.

I'm using this code to define it within my module, but its doesn't cover all possible scenarios.

```
var config_dir = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)+path.sep+'node_modules'+path.sep+'open-payments'+path.sep+'config';
process.env.NODE_CONFIG_DIR=config_dir
```

I need something that will tell my module where to look regardless of what or where the script is that's using my module.

Comment: Is your config directory in the same place relatively to your module files?

Comment: my config directory is in the root of my project directory. I also have a lib directory where my main module is located, and I have a test directory where I'm trying to implement some test scripts.

Comment: You're looking for [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) then.

Comment: thanks, I think that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)** to get the full path for the current executing script (i.e. not necessarily the one that was called with `node`, but the one where `__dirname` was queried).

See this question for more details: [How to get path to current script with node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133243/how-to-get-path-to-current-script-with-node-js)