# How can I get the absolute path to the gulpfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

How can I get the absolute path to the gulpfile (from the gulpfile itself)?

I wish to use the location as a reference for other relative paths.

Comment: Get the path from where? What's the relation between the gulpfile and wherever you need the path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gulpfile.js` is just a normal script file executed in node. From inside the file [`__filename`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_filename) will point to its path:

> **`__filename`** (String)
>
> The filename of the code being executed. This is the resolved absolute path of this code file. For a main program this is not necessarily the same filename used in the command line. The value inside a module is the path to that module file.

But probably you want the directory, not the script file:

> **`__dirname`** (String)
>
> The name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.

C.f. "[How do I get the path to the current script with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3133243/416224)"