# Create big files with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm completely new to Node.js so I have I question.

I'm writing a simple cli app that will create some files and directories.

For example if user inputs :

```
name-of-my-app init
```

It will create `index.html` with some html markup with indentation(like !DOCTYPE, head, body etc.)

Maybe I can create a file and then just move the ready file from my `node_modules/my-app` directory to the directory of the user(__dirname)?

The idea of my cli app is to init new projects with some .css and .js files. Also I want to use it globally(`npm install -g my-app`)

Hope you'll understand what I mean :)

Any advices?

Thank you very much for spending your precious time with my problem!

Comment: Yes; it is possible to create or copy files.  What don't you understand?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's your question. What problem are you facing?

Comment: @SLaks Well, sorry for not clearing it out. I mean if it's possible to just copy some files from app directory to user's I don't understand how can I grab the while from app directory while using my app globally?

Comment: @YegorGunko: So you're actually just asking how to get the path to the current file? Use `__dirname`.

Comment: @SLaks, yeah I mean if I use __dirname for grab a file then how to access directory in which user is 'staying' and place the file there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3133243/34397

Comment: @SLaks sorry for troubling you with stupid questions, but I still can't understand if I use my app globally the __dirname will refer to my app's root directory? Like : /usr/lib/node_modules/my-app?

Comment: You're looking for the current directory, not `__dirname`.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/learning/index.html). It Might be more suited to what you want.