# GitHub action self ref_name

Tags: github-actions

Within the action, how to get the ref (branch or version) of that action which has been called by a workflow?

In case I call my-action (v1) using:

```
steps:
  - uses: my-action@v1
```

I need to retrieve the value `v1` in my-action. But `${{ github.action_ref }}` only provides the ref of the caller (workflow), not the ref of the called action (my-action).

A solution would be to use in the workflow:

```
steps:
  - uses: my-action@v1
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.action_ref }}
```

But I would like to avoid asking the caller to specify this parameter and would prefer to retrieve it directly in the action itself. Is that possible?

I need to checkout the repository which contains the action into the caller repository:

```
runs: 
  using: composite 
  steps: 
  - name: Checkout current repository 
    uses: actions/checkout@v3 
    with: 
      path: main 
  - name: Checkout validation repository 
    uses: actions/checkout@v3 
    with: 
      repository: [ORG]/validation 
      ref: v1.5.3 
      path: validation
```

Comment: Interesting question, I wonder why you'd want that ref.

Comment: Because I need to checkout the repository which contains the action into the caller repository:

````
runs:
  using: composite
  steps:
  - name: Checkout current repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      path: main
  - name: Checkout validation repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v3
    with:
      repository: [ORG]/validation
      ref: v1.5.3
      path: validation
````

Comment: The runner has already checked out the action's repo at that ref for you in its working folder.

Comment: So I can use directly `${{ github.action_path }}`, thanks!

Comment: There are a few issues with `${{ github.action_path }}`, accessing the environment variable `${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH}` in bash or `$env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH` in powershell is a lot safer: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/716

Comment: I am in an action with bash shell but `${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH}` is not replaced.

Comment: Either $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH does not work with command: `working-directory: $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH`

Comment: `${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH}` should work in a bash shell *in a composite action*, just a `run:` in a normal workflow won't set this path. Can you share more of what your workflow looks like to allow us to help you better? You can't use the bash environment variable syntax to assign to an input of a step, but you should be able to `cd $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH` inside the run action without issues.

Answer (score 2):

For a typescript/javascript based action, [you should be able to grab the `__dirname` variable from node to get to the path where the action's git repo got checked out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3133313/736079).

In that folder you should be able to run a git command to grab the current sha that was checked out.

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

For [Composite Actions an environment variable exists](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) that should return the path where the repo was checked out:

> `GITHUB_ACTION_PATH`  The path where an action is located. This property is only supported in composite actions. You can use this path to access files located in the same repository as the action. For example, `/home/runner/work/_actions/repo-owner/name-of-action-repo/v1`